# How can I include an external script in my ReactJS app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React JS app where, on a specific pages, I show different job offers, one by one, tinder style. My client asked me to put one "widget" from an external website on the job offer. The widget is a "div" with an external script from another website. This script is a bunch of "document.write", not even a selector for the div... Small problem: the script isn't called, so the relevant code isn't added inside the div.

How can I make sure that a  tag I dynamically add will execute it's code? It doesn't even seem to get loaded in the "Network" tab of the website. The  with the script inside is down a bunch of React components.

Anyone has an idea on how I can make the script load even if it's dynamically added?

Comment: Code in script tags are processed when the page+script loads. Can you include a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Code Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Is your situation similar to this by any chance https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65473116/inserting-button-from-html-script-tag-in-react-js/65475568#65475568 ?

Comment: @NadiaChibrikova Yes, exactly! Thanks